# Связать Woocommerce c Mandrill

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email, вёрстка-email, mandrill

Дело в следующем:
Есть сайт на WP, к нему подключен магазин Woocommerce. Woocommerce шлет email с заказом конечному пользователю (стандартное письмо, стандартная верстка).

Есть красивые письма в формате html с необходимыми переменными (mc:editable, mc:repeatable) для Mandrill. Были задизайнены в figma при помощи плагина Emailify.

Так вот, в чем моя проблема - как мне заставить Wordpress (Woocommerce) слать мои дизайны, загруженные в Mandrill вместо стандартных шаблонов, учитывая то, что знаний кода у меня - ноль?

Кастомизация стандартных шаблонов плагинами получается не очень красивой, хотелось бы слать именно свои задизайненые письма

Comment: Какой помощи ты ждёшь от SO? Тут либо научиться верстать либо нанять того кто умеет.

Comment: я пытаюсь понять и разобраться как именно работает отправка шаблонов через Mandrill

Comment: Шаблоны ни чего не отправляют.  Ни через что. Шаблоны - это упрощенно говоря, дизайн, в который включен вызов функций.  https://woocommerce.com/posts/how-to-customize-emails-in-woocommerce/